# Batch: Concatinated filesnames into a CSV-File

Tags: csv, concatenation, filenames, batch-processing, dir

I want all filesnames of the files in a folder and subfolders in a csv-file. For that I wrote a batchscript which works just fine:

```
set "Folder=N:\myFolder\mySubFolder\mySubSubFolder"
dir /b "%Folder%">"Z:\worx\filenames.csv"
```

The content of filenames.csv is like:

```
N:\myFolder\file1.txt
N:\myFolder\mySubFolder\file2.txt
N:\myFolder\mySubFolder\mySubSubFolder\file3.txt
```

Now I want to concatenate each line in the csv-file. The result has to look like that:

```
The File:N:\myFolder\file1.txt#exists
The File:N:\myFolder\mySubFolder\file2.txt#exists
The File:N:\myFolder\mySubFolder\mySubSubFolder\file3.txt#exists
```

Does anybody know a simple way to do that?

I thought about another batchfile which just extends each line of the csv-file, but I am looking for an less complicate way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@echo off
set "Folder=N:\myFolder\mySubFolder\mySubSubFolder"
(for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /s /a-d "%Folder%" ') do echo The File:%%a#exists)>"Z:\worx\filenames.csv"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set "Folder=N:\myFolder\mySubFolder\mySubSubFolder"
(
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('dir /b "%Folder%"') do echo(The File:%%x#exists
)>"Z:\worx\filenames.csv"
```

Should work. The filenames are applied to `%%x` and output with the fixed text fore and aft. The `"delims="` makes each `dir /b` line one string not a series of tokens. The parentheses surrounding the (for...) makes the redirector output any `echo`ed text into the destination file. The `>` redirector creates the destination file anew. `>>` would append to any existing file.

You may wish to consider adding `/a-d` to your `dir` switches to suppress directorynames.